# How to default select drop value with HTML and angular 9

Tags: html, angular8, updates, angular9

After I update my angular-cli from Angular 8 to 9 select drop isn't work.
He said for a problem for no reason how can I fix this issue?

I want only default value in my select as option 1

**HTML**

```
            <select [(ngModel)]="Object.x">
              <option [value]="size" disabled>Size</option>
              <option value="S">S</option>
              <option value="M">M</option>
              <option value="L">L</option>
            </select>
```

**Error** (with [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCfTj.jpg))

```
Time: 323ms
: Compiled successfully.

    ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.html:53:32 - error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'.

    53               <option [value]="size" disabled>Size</option>
                                      ~~~~

      src/app/home/home.component.ts:20:16
        20   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.
    src/app/home/home.component.html:53:32 - error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'.

    53               <option [value]="size" disabled>Size</option>
                                      ~~~~

      src/app/home/home.component.ts:20:16
        20   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.
```

At this way it works but sends that problem in my terminal. How can I fix it?

Comment: help plz.......

Comment: sorry for hard question I fixed it anyway you can lock it